# How can i loc all data from my list of dataframes using a for loop?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to handle lists of data frames and trying to use/learn for loops.

My first question is, is it normal to use a list of data frames? Because I don't see much information on the internet.

But I am trying to do calculations on all data frames the same time, before this i would do a lot of copy and pasting to handle multiple dataframes and I want to get rid of that. So I have a problem now, this is my script:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np

## 1 0.0290
A_start_01 = datetime.datetime(2022,6,8, 16,30,0)
S_start_01 = datetime.datetime(2022,6,9, 0,30,0)
D_start_01 = datetime.datetime(2022,6,11,   11,50,0)
D_end_01 = datetime.datetime(2022,6, 12,   22,41,0)



path = r'C:\Users\###\OneDrive - ###\###\Pyth\data\flume' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=(0), header=0, skiprows=(30), delimiter = ';', names = ['datetime', 'x_axis', 'y_axis', 'z_axis'], parse_dates=['datetime'])
    li.append(df)

for index in li:
    index['gradient'] = np.abs(np.gradient(index['x_axis'])) + np.abs(np.gradient(index['x_axis'])) + np.abs(np.gradient(index['x_axis']))
  
    
for index in li:
    mask = (df.index > A_start_01) & (df.index <= D_end_01)    
    df.loc[mask]
```

So I managed to do some calculations on all of the data frames at the same time, But the last part where  I want to use 'loc' to cut my data frames into the same time period does not work. I can do it separately but I do not know how to use the for loop for this.

And after that I want to synchronize the datatime. This because I have 8 samples that made a measurement every 25 seconds. And they have the same interval but I would like to synchronize them with the datetime of my first df li[0].

I hope someone could help me, I learned a lot in python but this for loop is really what I still don't understand.

Greetings,

ps. this  is 1 out of 8 data frames that are in list 'li':

```
                        x_axis  y_axis  z_axis  gradient
datetime                                                 
2022-05-16 12:20:03.719   0.220  -0.010  -0.936    0.0330
2022-05-16 12:20:28.719   0.209  -0.018  -0.927    0.0105
2022-05-16 12:20:53.719   0.213  -0.026  -0.936    0.0225
2022-05-16 12:21:18.719   0.224  -0.022  -0.944    0.0345
2022-05-16 12:21:43.719   0.236  -0.018  -0.940    0.0660
                        ...     ...     ...       ...
2022-06-13 09:39:38.719  -0.083  -0.014  -0.957    0.0060
2022-06-13 09:40:03.719  -0.087  -0.018  -0.949    0.0165
2022-06-13 09:40:28.719  -0.094  -0.018  -0.962    0.0060
2022-06-13 09:40:53.719  -0.083  -0.018  -0.944    0.6855
2022-06-13 09:41:18.719  -0.551   0.006  -0.940    1.4040

1:
2022-05-16 12:18:23.719;-0.996;0.022;0.235
2022-05-16 12:18:48.719;0.008;0.018;1.154
2022-05-16 12:19:13.719;0.004;0.014;1.141
2022-05-16 12:19:38.719;-1.134;0.034;0.380

2:
2022-06-06 05:38:12.719;0.460;-0.625;0.613
2022-06-06 05:38:37.719;0.429;-0.625;0.645
2022-06-06 05:39:02.719;0.460;-0.625;0.645
2022-06-06 05:39:27.719;0.429;-0.625;0.613

3:
2022-05-16 12:05:54.719;0.500;-0.438;0.774
2022-05-16 12:06:19.719;0.063;0.000;1.000
2022-05-16 12:06:44.719;1.000;-0.156;0.194
2022-05-16 12:07:09.719;-0.531;0.125;-0.839
```

Comment: Loops perform actions sequentially. Have you considered the option of combining them when downloading from csv files and further processing them?

Comment: Yes i am trying to combine them, I want them to have the same datetimeindex, so they need to be loced into the same interval and synchronized

Comment: Can you place the first 3-4 lines from any 3 csv files in the question?

Comment: Yes I will do that now

Comment: Okay I put in the raw data

Comment: And add the steps that you need to calculate and a sample of what you want to get.

Comment: I want to cut with the time interval, as expressed in my first post.

Comment: Well I can tell what I want to calculate but I just did that in my question. And I can not give a example because I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245730/discussion-between---and-simondl).